# Canvas event listener not working

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js

Canvas event listener is not triggered while there is a change in canvas

```
    var canvas = canvas(300,100);
```

Attaching event listener

```
  canvas.on({
    'mouse:up' : modifiedHandler,
    'mouse:down' : modifiedHandler,
    'object:modified' : modifiedHandler
  });
```

This event listener is not triggered  while there is change in canvas

```
  var modifiedHandler = function (event) {

    console.log('trigger') // Not triggered
  };
```

This function returns canvas

```
  function canvas(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.object = object();

    function object() {
      return new fabric.Canvas('id', {
        selection: false,
        height: this.height,
        width: this.width
      });
    }
    return this.object;
  }
```

Adding the fiddle reference [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5KKQ2/4012/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `modifiedHandler` first before you use it.

```
 var modifiedHandler = function (event) {
     alert('trigger');  // trigger
  };
  canvas.on({
    'mouse:up' : modifiedHandler,
    'mouse:down' : modifiedHandler,
    'object:modified' : modifiedHandler
  })
```